# Most Efficient way of searching a List of values in an SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am working on a C# Win-forms Application which is connected to SQL Server Database. I have a situation where I have to parse data from an Excel sheet and search each value in all columns of a table. And at the end display the rows of table whose value matched.

Now what I am doing is

1. I have parsed the whole Excel sheet into DataTable
2. I have a stored procedure in SQL server which take a string input and search it in all column of table and return a row if any matched.
3. Now I pass each value of the Datatable(extracted from excel sheet) to the stored procedure for searching.

Kindly guide me whether it is an efficient way, or give me suggestion for achieving it efficiently.

Comment: Do you have only one column in excel ? i mean you will search only one value from each row of excel in SQL  ?

Comment: Could you show us your actually code for better understanding ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad, No I have multiple columns in excel sheet

Comment: And you will have to search each column value of excel in sql ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Exactly

Comment: But it will be one at a time ?

Comment: I parse the whole Excel sheet into a datatable, then I search each column of datatable in sql but one at a time

Comment: You can pass the whole datatable to sql and than in SQL you can use loop or cursor in SQL to extract values and search in table/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79732/discussion-between-wixxey-and-mairaj-ahmad).

Comment: The problem is, SQL tables != worksheets, despite the superficial resemblance. In SQL, all data that is "the same" ought to be in the same column. There are plenty of tools for working with columnar data, but little support for working *across* multiple columns. Any reason for not just using Excel?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know about the difference of the two, for the sake to we have define a specific format for excel sheet and its data column wise. and reason for not just using excel is I want to use proper DB for storing, searching and report building

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Table Valued` parameter and than in SQL you can use `cursor` or `loop` over the passed table and search each column in SQL table. Here is a simple example.

In database create a new `Tpye`

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SearchInDB] AS TABLE(
[Id] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

And in SP you will pass this type from C# code. Your SP will receive it like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourSPNameHere]  
@DataToSearch dbo.SearchInDB ReadOnly  
AS  
BEGIN  
--Your SP logic here
END
```

And in your code you will create a `DataTable` and fill datatable with values and pass it to SP like this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
//Add rows in datatable with values
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Id"] = 10;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

//Now pass this table to SP as parameter
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "@DataToSearch"; 
parameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured; 
parameter.Value = dt;
```

**Note**

I have added only one column you have to add other column if needed. To get values from parameter passed to SP you will have to use loop or use cursor. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22392/SQL-Server-Table-Valued-Parameters) is a link of another example

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server SSIS packages , to directly import excel into database table and can search the table using loop or cursor in stored procedure

Comment: And can you prove that it's the most efficient way?

Comment: Yes instead of making multiple database call , at once the excel file will be imported. So this is one of the efficent way.